# Find the distance between function and linear space in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to find the distance between $f(t)=sin(t)$ and linear space $V=\mathbb{R}<1,t,t^2>$ in Hilbert space $L^2_{\mathbb{R}} ([0,\pi], \mu)$, where $d \mu(t)=dt$.
I know that firstly I need to orthogonalize $\{1,t,t^2\}$:

$$ {P_0(t) = 1}$$
$$P_1(t) = t-(t, \frac{P_0(t)}{||P_0(t)||}) \cdot \frac{P_0(t)}{||P_0(t)||} = t-(t, P_0(t)) \cdot \frac{1}{||P_0(t)||^2} = t-\frac{\pi}{2} $$

$$P_2(t) = t^2-(t, P_0(t)) \cdot \frac{1}{||P_0(t)||^2} -(t, P_1(t)) \cdot \frac{t-\frac{\pi}{2}}{||P_1(t)||^2} =t^2-t\pi+\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

$P_V(sin(t))=(sin(t), P_0(t)) \cdot \frac{1}{||P_0(t)||^2} +(sin(t), P_1(t)) \cdot \frac{t-\frac{\pi}{2}}{||P_1(t)||^2} +(sin(t), P_2(t)) \cdot \frac{t^2-t\pi+\frac{\pi^2}{6}}{||P_2(t)||^2}$=...

And then we can find the distance as
$$dist(f, V)=||f-P_Vf||$$

Is my idea correct? I get very "volume" results and that's t feels like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: In my opinion the idea is correct. You can slightly simplify calculations by observing that the distance is the same as the distance from $\cos t$ from the subspace of polynomials of degree less than or equal $2,$ i.e. from $V={\rm span}\{1,t,t^2\}$ in $L^2(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ This can be achieved by translation in $t,$ as $\sin (t)=\cos(t-\pi/2).$ Observe that $\cos t$ is orthogonal to $t$ due to the fact that $t\cos t$ is an odd function.  It suffices to find the distance from $\cos t$ to two dimensional space $V'$ spanned by $1$ and $t^2,$ because $V'\perp t.$  This requires less calculations.

Comment: You can get proper norm bars $\|$ by using `\|` rather than `||`. And you can get the right font and spacing for operators like $\operatorname{dist}$ using `\operatorname{dist}`.